# Fruit cherry leaves got eaten by something?

Tags: fruit-trees, diseases, leaves, bugs, cherries

I have bing fruit cherry tree and the leaves look like these

[image]

[image]

It is randomly at different spots. Is this something I should be concerning? Is it caused by disease or some bugs eating them?

**UPDATE 1**

Adding one more photo. I am in Pacific Northwest and it is May when I look at this.

[image]

Comment: Not sure, first picture looks like hopper damage to me but the second picture seems to tell a different story. Perhaps someone else can tell but imho, I would need more evidence, more pictures.

Comment: @Rob I added one more photo from my phone. Let me know.

Comment: Great, I am more confident that this is die-back and not bugs. However, I am not confident as to what is causing it.

Comment: @Rob So you mean it is more weather related? Cold and hot suddenly? There are not many spots like that. I would say maybe 3-5% of the entire 10 feet tree.